# kotlin multiplatform and maven

Tags: maven, gradle, kotlin

Is it possible to have a kotlin multiplateform project in maven?

I found only plugin for the kotlin multiplatform in gradle .

I need to build an librairy both in js, kotlin and java

Comment: If there is no Maven plugin, the answer is probably no

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, current multiplatform model is highly tied to Gradle and is benefiting from it's unique features like Gradle Metadata.

Still, you can file an issue on that at https://kotl.in/issue, it may sound reasonable to additionally support Maven when Multiplatform is stabilized with Gradle.